# Streaming RTMP from iOS to Wowza , RTMPAuthentication not working

Tags: ios, authentication, rtmp, wowza, encoder

I am using rtmp stream with iOS H264 and AAC encoder . I need source security using either ModuleRTMPAuthenticate or ModuleOnconnectAuthenticate2 . However the logic inside of my custom class is never hit in either case.

When using ModuleRTMPAuthenticate it blocks the stream and send back disconnect whereas in ModuleOnconnectAuthenticate2 the stream just starts publishing inspite of wrong credentials .

I have asked many questions on this topic in wowza forums earlier too however not one of them have been replied to .

1. https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-configure-security-using-wowza-streaming-engine-manager
2. https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/6825/authentication-from-java-rtmp-publisher.html
3. https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-enable-username-password-authentication-for-rtmp-and-rtsp-publishing

PS : The modules works perfectly with Wowza gocoder and Flash Media Live Encoder . Also major part of my code is from [here](https://github.com/pili-engineering/PLCameraStreamingKit)

Comment: Have you tried [debugging this way](http://streamtoolbox.com/debugging-wowza-module)? If you send me [Wrench](http://streamtoolbox.com/wrench) logs or just contact via that site I can help.

Comment: Hello jabal , thanks for the reply . I checked out Wrench and looks like it have player authentication ("how to set up Wrench to perform authorization on your stream players ") but i couldnot find stream source authentication . please suggest any link to Wowza Source side security if Wrench supports it .  Also note that im looking at non-flash encoder since I am all for open source standards which flash isnt .

Comment: Wrench is symmetric and basically all features including authentication, access control and pay-per-minute apply to encoders.